# ValueError: Content-Type header is "text/html", not "application/json" django python

Tags: python, json, django, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to run a test for one of my views but I keep getting this error `raise ValueError( ValueError: Content-Type header is "text/html", not "application/json"`

Here is the view function

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.POST.get("action") == "post":
        product_id = int(request.POST.get("productid"))
        product_qty = int(request.POST.get("productqty"))
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        cart.add(product=product, qty=product_qty)
        product_qty = cart.__len__()
        response = JsonResponse({"qty": product_qty})
        return response
```

Here is the URL path

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = "cart"

urlpatterns = [
    path("add/", views.add_to_cart, name="add_to_cart"),
]
```

And lastly the test

```
def test_add_to_cart(self):
        response = self.client.post(reverse('cart:add_to_cart'), {
            "productid": 3,
            "productqty": 1,
            "action":'post',
        }, xhr=True)
        print(response.status_code)
        self.assertTrue(response.json(), {'qty':4})
        response = self.client.post(reverse('cart:add_to_cart'), {
            "productid": 2,
            "productqty": 1,
            "action":'post',
        }, xhr=True)
        self.assertTrue(response.json(), {'qty':3})
```

Comment: Instead of printing the `response.status_code` you should be asserting. Check that value is what you expect _first_.

Comment: That was for debugging initially, I should have removed it, I will test the status code and update the question

Answer (score -1):

Everything is actually working fine, the error came from the `self.assertTrue` that I used;

I was actually meant to use `self.assertEqual`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).